# Custom Angular Component using ion-datetime doesn't behave properly if untouched

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a build a custom angular date-picker component that have two-way binding (it get value from firestore and if the user modify it, it update to firestore).

Here is my HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item id="{{'open-date-' + pickerId}}">
      <ion-label>{{label}}</ion-label>
      <ion-note slot="end">{{selectedDate | date: 'HH:mm'}}</ion-note>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-modal trigger="{{'open-date-' + pickerId}}" [cssClass]="'bottom-end'">
      <ng-template>
        <ion-datetime
          presentation="time"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
          (ionChange)="onDateChange(selectedDate)"
          size="cover"
          [showDefaultButtons]="true"
          cancelText="Annuler"
          doneText="Valider"
          minuteValues="0,15,30,45">
        </ion-datetime>
      </ng-template>
    </ion-modal>
  </ion-list>
</ion-item>
```

Here is my TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datetime-picker',
  templateUrl: './datetime-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datetime-picker.component.scss'],
})
export class DatetimePickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() pickerId?: string;
  @Input() label?: string;
  @Input() selectedDate: Date = new Date();
  @Output() selectedDateChange = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onDateChange(newDate: Date): void {
    console.log('onDateChange', newDate);
    this.selectedDate = newDate;
    this.selectedDateChange.emit(this.selectedDate);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it only works only when I click on the date, and use the "rolling" time picker and then validate.
If I just open, and click validate, I'm suppose to update the firestore value with the current time (default value when opening the time picker), it's an undefined date.

I try to use setter and getter, I try to use ngModelChange, and more solutions, but the problem is still exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [`ionFocus`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#events) event and setting the current time and emitting the event

html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item id="{{'open-date-' + pickerId}}">
      <ion-label>{{label}}</ion-label>
      <ion-note slot="end">{{selectedDate | date: 'HH:mm'}}</ion-note>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-modal trigger="{{'open-date-' + pickerId}}" [cssClass]="'bottom-end'">
      <ng-template>
        <ion-datetime
          presentation="time"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
          (ionChange)="onDateChange(selectedDate)"
          (ionFocus)="onDatePickerFocus()"
          size="cover"
          [showDefaultButtons]="true"
          cancelText="Annuler"
          doneText="Valider"
          minuteValues="0,15,30,45">
        </ion-datetime>
      </ng-template>
    </ion-modal>
  </ion-list>
</ion-item>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datetime-picker',
  templateUrl: './datetime-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datetime-picker.component.scss'],
})
export class DatetimePickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() pickerId?: string;
  @Input() label?: string;
  @Input() selectedDate: Date = new Date();
  @Output() selectedDateChange = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onDateChange(newDate: Date): void {
    console.log('onDateChange', newDate);
    this.selectedDate = newDate;
    this.selectedDateChange.emit(this.selectedDate);
  }

  onDatePickerFocus(): void {
    console.log('onDatePickerFocus', newDate);
    if(!this.selectedDate) {
        this.selectedDate = new Date();
    }
    this.selectedDateChange.emit(this.selectedDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest in my question. I tried your solution (I had to add newDate as parameter to onDatePickerFocus because it was undefined.) and when I click "ok", it shows undefined as well as the expected hour on the log in 2 rows. The problem is, when I click cancel, it still shows the row of the value that is currently in firestore. This is not a 'big' problem but it creates a request to firestore to update the value to the same value. It could be fixed elsewhere but I feel it's moving the problem away. I wish value could be sent to the parent properly when clicked "ok".